# Wireguard Error: Device for nexthop is not up

Tags: linux, debian, wireguard

Такая проблема: не хочет работать Wireguard на Debian 12. В чём может быть косяк, ибо видно, что клиент не желает подключаться. Аналогичный конфиг на Винде прекрасно работает.
Прилагаю конфиг:

```
[Interface]
PrivateKey = ###
Address = 10.8.0.42/32
DNS = 8.8.8.8, 1.1.1.1

[Peer]
PublicKey = ##
Endpoint = []:51820
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/1, 128.0.0.0/1
PersistentKeepalive = 20
```

Статус включенного wireguard:

```
root@egor-main:~# systemctl status wg-quick@wg0
● wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/wg-quick@.service; disabled; preset: enabled)
     Active: active (exited) since Mon 2023-11-06 22:06:57 MSK; 51s ago
       Docs: man:wg-quick(8)
             man:wg(8)
             https://www.wireguard.com/
             https://www.wireguard.com/quickstart/
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg-quick.8
             https://git.zx2c4.com/wireguard-tools/about/src/man/wg.8
    Process: 7434 ExecStart=/usr/bin/wg-quick up wg0 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
   Main PID: 7434 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
        CPU: 56ms

ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main systemd[1]: Starting wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0...
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] ip link add wg0 type wireguard
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] wg setconf wg0 /dev/fd/63
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] ip -4 address add 10.8.0.42/32 dev wg0
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] ip link set mtu 1340 up dev wg0
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7464]: [#] resolvconf -a tun.wg0 -m 0 -x
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] ip -4 route add 128.0.0.0/1 dev wg0
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main wg-quick[7434]: [#] ip -4 route add 0.0.0.0/1 dev wg0
ноя 06 22:06:57 egor-main systemd[1]: Finished wg-quick@wg0.service - WireGuard via wg-quick(8) for wg0.
```

Вывод ip a:

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1420 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 90:2b:34:a7:5e:a6 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.0.42/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.40.42/24 brd 192.168.40.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 192.168.88.42/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global noprefixroute enp3s0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::922b:34ff:fea7:5ea6/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
13: wg0: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP> mtu 1340 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/none
```